# can we use this implementation of array in which its size is variable n and m

Tags: arrays, c, variables

We have declared an array with variable dimension/size .

Can we use this implementation as we have already receive our values

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    printf("\nLet create an array ");
    printf("\n enter the row of array :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nenter the column of array :");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    int a[n][m];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Since C99, C allows variable-length arrays.

Comment: Depends on how large m and n are likely to be, and how big your stack is. See: https://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/04/07/c99s-vlas-are-evil/

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is valid in standard C, it's called a *variable-length array* (VLA), a feature which has been around for ages by now. In 2011 they were made an optional feature, but I'm not aware of any modern C compliant compiler that doesn't support them.

Though you might want to sanitize the input before declaring the array. Declaring large arrays in local scope is never a good idea and can lead to stack overflow.

Comment: I thought MSVC didn't?  (Though maybe you exclude it from "modern" or "compliant".)

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed MS is neither modern nor compliant.